# Changing grid-color of Cropping tool of Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photo-editing, cropping, grid

When we use Lightroom, cropping tool utilize a grid which is White in color.

Problem is: when i edit some whitish or light-colored photo, the grid is almost invisible. In that case, I cannot pin-point rule-of-third's crossing points properly.

Is there any regular or hack-ish way to change the grid-color ?

Comment: People have been asking for this for a long time, but there is still no official way (http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-lightroom-5/lightroom-5-features/). As a workaround you could temporarily change the exposure.

Answer (score 1):

You suggested you are fine with a "hack" more or less.
You could create a virtual copy of the image, and throw the exposure of that virtual copy significantly darker to help with the visibility of the grid. Once you have the crop as desired, sync the crop only back to the original master image, and delete the virtual copy. It would take a few extra seconds but not too long.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but, problem is that, every time i will try to re-adjust the re-crop, i will have to go through it ...
by hackish way, i meant if it could be done by changing some registry value or some hexa-edit into some binary property file. i wish i know.